# method in ArangoRepository extension class using COLLECT in query annotation to group by and count not working

Tags: spring-data, arangodb, aql

I have a simple node like this below

```
@Document("users")
public class User {
  @Id // db document field: _key
  private String id;

  @ArangoId // db document field: _id
  private String arangoId;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String country;

  public User() {
    super();
  }

  public User(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public User(String id, String country) {
    this.id = id;
    this.country = country;
  }

  // getter & setter

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + firstName + ", surname=" + lastName + "]";
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

here is the repository class but the method getListOfCountryAndNumUsers returns null even though i have inserted users with different countries into the database.

```
public interface UserRepository extends ArangoRepository<User, String> {

@Query("FOR u IN users COLLECT country = u.country WITH COUNT INTO length RETURN 
  {\"country\" : country, \"count\" : length }")
  Iterable<CountryAndNumUsers> getListOfCountryAndNumUsers();

}
```

I think the problem could be with the the syntax of my query in the query annotation. I didnt see any direct example of using collect operation in the spring data arango db part of arangodb documentation [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/spring-data-reference-repositories-queries.html) but I saw the collect operation in the section "high level operations" of arangoDb documentation [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-collect.html)

Please Help. Thanks. !

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered my error. It was in a class I didn't add in the question. That is the class for the return object of the method getListOfCountryAndNumUsers()
i.e class CountryAndNumUsers.

```
public class CountryAndNumUsers {
  private String country;
  private Integer numberOfUsers;

  public CountryAndNumUsers(String country, Integer numberOfUsers) {
    this.country = country;
    this.numberOfUsers = numberOfUsers;
  }

  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public Integer getNumberOfUsers() {
    return numberOfUsers;
  }
}
```

so there was a mapping mismatch since the query returns an object with different field names. I changed the query to this below so that it matches

```
@Query("FOR u IN users COLLECT country = u.country WITH COUNT INTO length RETURN {\"country\" : country, \"numberOfUsers\" : length }")
```